# Define $f$ on $\Bbb R$ by $f(x)=x^3$ for $x\ge0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\lt 0$. Find all $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $f^{(n)}$ exists on all of $\Bbb R$.

Tags: analysis

> Define $f$ on $\Bbb R$ by $f(x)=x^3$ for $x\ge0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\lt 0$. Find all $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $f^{(n)}$ exists on all of $\Bbb R$.

I am studying for Analysis midterm.

I saw this question and I am not sure what exactly f^(n) means.

Is it talking about a derivative? or something else?

I am not 100% sure. It looks pretty simple.

any tips or suggestions would be great!

Comment: Yes, $f^{(n)}$ is fairly standard notation for the $n$th derivative $$\frac{d^n f}{dx^n}$$

Comment: @T.Bongers Oh okay... So like 1st derivative is f^(1)??

Comment: @T.Bongers hi T. Bongers so n can be 1,2,3? correct. (till 3rd derivative f^(3)=6)

Comment: Yes. Any natural number is okay.

Comment: @Vladhagen any natural numbers?? what?? what about f^(5) ??

Comment: $f^{(n)}$ is notation for $$ \frac{d^ny}{dx^n}$$ and $f^n(x)$ is notation for $(f(x))^n = f(x) \cdot f(x) ... \cdot f(x)$

Comment: Hence in general $f^{n^{(m)}}\neq f^{(n)^m}$,  but that notation is sick ...

Comment: The fifth derivative exists. It is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f^{(n)}(x)$
means the $n$-th derivative of $f$
at $x$.

For your problem, $f(x)$
is defined on two disjoint domains
as a different function on each domain.
These separate functions
are "nice" in their own domains,
so the only problem can be
where the domains meet,
which is at zero.

So what you need to do
is to see what the derivatives
of each function are at zero
and check if they agree or disagree.

The rest is up to you.
I may have said too much.

Comment: so f^(4) = 0 for x^3. and the latter one is f^(0)=0. is that correct?

Comment: Please learn how to enter expressions. In your case, $f^{(4)}(x^3) = 0$. How about $f^{(3)}(x^3)$? What happens at $x=0$?